# Parse.com cannot get ParseRelation from Object

Tags: android, parse-platform

i try to retrieve relation from an object. but i get an error (This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.). 
I tried everything, but i get this error.

```
public void Member() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
            "PrivateDialog");
    try {
        mFriendsRelation = query.get(relationid).getRelation("Member");


    } catch (ParseException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            mFriendsRelation.getQuery().findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseUser> friends, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        mFriends = friends;
                        if (member.getAdapter() == null) {
                            member.setAdapter(new MemberAdapter(member.getContext(), mFriends, R.layout.member_group_item));
                            member.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            member.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(GroupDialogActivity.this));
                            member.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                        } else {
                            // refill the adapter!
                            Log.i("Refill", "todo");
                        }
                    } else {

                        Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: `query.get` followed by `query.findInBackground` seems to be the issue. You can't make consecutive network calls on a ParseObject

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the fast answer.  what should i Do?

Comment: Not sure. It's been awhile since I used Parse. I was just explaining the reason for the error